# Help me find sci-fi animated short film with a killer effect for FTL transition and journey

Tags: story-identification, animation

Some details:

- I must have reached it via io9.com, gizmodo or imgur.
- It was probably within 6 last months.
- The animation is really good and realistic for what it is.
- No dialogue.
- ~5 minutes.
- Animated (CGI, futuristic, real life like)

**Synopsis**:

A pilot in full suit walking towards a ship, you can see on lookers from a distance that could be scientists or superior officers. Once in his cockpit, the hangar fades and begins some sort of FTL transition where the ship appears to not move at all, but is encapsulated by some sort of bubble which then collapses on it self and causes the ship to be instantly transported to an inhabited planet.

The ship then begins to fly off. The pilot sees a series of abstract objects inside his cockpit dashboard (implying other destinations) and you realize that the first objective is the first of the destinations. The pilot reaches a place that does not seem natural forming, landing and going towards the center of this place, the pilot searches with the aid of a scanner on this arm (a helm piece) but does not find anything. You then see the FTL transition as before and the ship is once again in a different world. The new planet is different, but reaches a similar non-natural looking place as before.

This continues with several more scenes where you can detect the frustration of the pilot as the places to visit run down. Upon reaching the last place to visit, a signal is detected and the pilot races towards it. It seems the signal is getting weaker but reaches it in time. Eureka! It is found, then the pilot is transitioned back to the hangar where everything started. You realize it must have been some sort of test.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the film you're looking for is the title sequence for [IFCC (Independent Festival of Creative Communication) 2017](http://ifcc-croatia.com/). It showcases a pilot in full space suit, walking towards a ship that seemingly travels from destination to destination by folding space. It even has the arm scanner. :)

The official page of the project, along with concept arts and making-of videos, is available [here](https://www.behance.net/gallery/50748713/IFCC-2017-Main-Titles).

Comment: Wow! I think you've hit the nail right on the head there! It's a beautiful film, how did you find it?

Comment: I never realised that the International Federation of Clinical Chemistry were such good film makers.

Comment: @Gallifreyan In my profession I study a lot of motion graphics work and this was a featured title on artofthetitle.com - I had seen it a month or so ago and it apparently made quite the impression since it jogged my memory.

And SQB - Thank you for the warm welcome! I'll check it out :)

Comment: I saw some making-of videos after some googling - it was _very_ impressive. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: Thanks crichins!! Exactly, you just made my day and it's so satisfying to see it again.

Answer (score -6):

I think it's either

- *Voyagers*,
- *Sumer*,
- or *Planet Unknown*

They're the best ones I've got after research.

Comment: Please provide any information that suggests it's those films to help the asker quickly read if it's the right film.

Comment: Could you at list link those here, so people don't have to go places to find them?

Comment: List those names at Google and see

Comment: __That is not how we answer questions. Please list one work per answer, and provide details as to why you think those are the films the asker is looking for.__

Comment: Also, none of the __4__ films named "Voyagers" or something similar fit the description. And none of the other two films you listed do as well.